# Legend Title in leaflet using GetLegendGraphic

Tags: javascript, leaflet, legend, title, geoserver

Can anyone please explain me how to define **legend title** in javascript/leaflet using GetLegendGraphic for layers from Geoserver? I have tried many things, like:

1. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28286/how-to-add-a-title-in-a-getlegendgraphic-request) I tried to make this rule in Geoserver Style section of individual layers.
2. [Here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Legend-Title-tc4987789.html#none) I also found good discussion but not really a solution.
3. Also read [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html) at the very begining and I basically just need this simple text as "USA Population" in the example.
4. And I was also thinking about defining it with decorations tag... in Geoserver directory, as stated [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.1.0/user/advanced/wmsdecoration.html), but I don't have the subdirectory layouts in my installation destination.
5. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307647/leaflet-adding-a-legend-title) sounded very simple but I'd like to use Legend generated from the Geoserver, since that works very well.

I also tried writing simply `"...&legend_options=title:"LEGEND"..."` , `"legendTitle:true"` or similar variations in the request, but it doesn't work either. Here is my code:

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
legend.onAdd = function (map) {
        div.innerHTML +=
        '<img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/WORKSPACE/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.1.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=WORKSPACE:Layer_NAME&legend_options=forceLabels:on&fontName:Arial;fontSize=14" alt="legend" width="145" height="130">';
    return div;
    };
```

Is there some problem generally with Geoserver not showing the legend title? Please help me, it is really annoying that this apparently simple thing isn't working :S

Answer (score 0):

The legend title is taken from the title of the layer you are displaying when you use the [decorators](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/decoration.html). You'll need to create a layouts directory and create a simple xml file there.

However, there is no way to add a title to a `GetLegendGraphic` request. Since you know the title of the layer you can just add it using JavaScript at the position of your choice, in the font of your choice. See this [discussion](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Legend-Title-tc4987789.html#none) on the mailing list for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Ian! 

Do you happen do have some example for such XML file?

Comment: Ok so I wrote very simple XML code in directory layouts, literally only this:
`<layout>
    <decoration type="legend" affinity="bottom,left" />
</layout>
`
As a result I get Legend with title but all over the map. Has anyone any thoughts on why this might be and how to fix it?

Comment: are you requesting tiles? if so each and every tile is a separate request and gets decorated.

Comment: Yes, I got it in the meantime that the problem is with tiles (I've found some help [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html)).

Now I tried to follow the instructions and I've set the `tiled:true` as well as `tilesorigin`. Here is where I encounter some problems. When setting `tilesorigin` to any value from [0,0] to some meaningful like coordinates of bottom left, the result is the same: two legends appearing at some unlogic (always the same) place on the map. Is it even possible to set legend right when using tiles? Thank you!

Comment: None of that is relevant, if you request tiles you will get a legend on each one. Why not request the getLegendGraphic and write in the title using JavaScript/CSS